# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'entitiy' of type 'ICollection<entity>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am aware of other questions on the same topic, however I have tried their solutions and none have worked for my code.
I am configuring a one-to-many relationship with one Account with many JoinedClassIds.

**Account.cs**

```
public class Account {
        // Actual account info
        [Key]
        public int _id { get; set; }

        public string _name { get; set; }
        public string _email { get; set; }

        public ICollection<JoinedClassId> JoinedClasses { get; set; }
}
```

**JoinedClassId.cs**

```
[Keyless]
    public class JoinedClassId {
        public int classIdNumber { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext**

```
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JoinedClassId> JoinedClassIds { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasMany(acc => acc.JoinedClasses)
                .WithOne(jcid => jcid.Account);
            modelBuilder.Entity<JoinedClassId>()
                .HasOne(jc => jc.Account)
                .WithMany(acc => acc.JoinedClasses);
            modelBuilder.Entity<JoinedClassId>()
                .HasNoKey();
        }
```

I get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
> relationship represented by navigation 'Account.JoinedClasses' of type
> 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the
> relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
> attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.'

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why is `JoinedClassId` marked as `Keyless`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Keyless` entities cannot participate in two way relationships. They can only contain reference navigation to other regular entities (entities with key). Also, regular entities cannot contain navigation properties to keyless entity types. What causing the issue in your case is, your `Account` entity contains the navigation property `JoinedClasses`, which is a collection of `Keyless` entity.

For details - [Keyless entity types characteristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations)

1. Remove the `[Keyless]` attribute from `JoinedClassId` entity
2. Add a new key property or mark the `classIdNumber` property as key
3. Add a foreign-key property (optional)

```
public class JoinedClassId 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }    // added key property
    public int classIdNumber { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }    // added foreign-key property
    
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can configure as -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasMany(acc => acc.JoinedClasses)
        .WithOne(jcid => jcid.Account)
        .HasForeignKey(p=> p.AccountId);  // if you have added a foreign-key property
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your classes:

```
public class Account {
       
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<JoinedClass> JoinedClasses { get; set; }
}

    public class JoinedClass {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClassIdNumber { get; set; }

        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
```

If you use EF Net5 , you don't need OnModelCreating  fluent Api code. Delete all tables from db  and migrate again